# Headers not sticking when scrolling using CSS Sticky property

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, sticky

I have a simple calendar view which statically can be coded as the React component below. There is a parent container and it contains two containers `timeslot` and `days`. I want them next to each other so I used flex property. Now I want container to be some fixed size and want the overflow items to scroll. When I scroll I want headers to stick. The `timeHeader` and `dayHeader` stops sticking after I scroll 40% of the vertical length.

[Rendered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZF40.png)

[Not sticking header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx1CF.png)

```
import React from "react";
import "./Test.css";

function Test() {
    return (
        <div className="parent">
            <div className="timeslot">
                <div className="timeHeader">Time</div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>7:00 a.m</li>
                        <li>8:00 a.m</li>
                        <li>9:00 a.m</li>
                        <li>10:00 a.m</li>
                        <li>11:00 a.m</li>
                        <li>12:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>1:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>2:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>3:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>4:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>5:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>6:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>7:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>8:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>9:00 p.m</li>
                        <li>10:00 p.m</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="days">
                <div className="dayHeader">Days</div>
                <div className="dayslots">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

and its CSS

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.timeHeader {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.timeslot {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
}

.days {
    flex: 5;
}

li {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.dayslots {
    display: flex;
}

.dayHeader {
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

The data inside the li tag, you can ignore it, it could be anything. All I want to fix is Time Header to stick all the time. Day header to stick when I scroll vertically and time i.e 7:00am... to stick when I scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want container to be some fixed size.

For flex items to shrink over their content size to fit `parent`, [set the the childs' min-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size/36247448#36247448) (or height) to 0, i.e., add `min-width:0` on the `timeslot` and `days` container to allow them to fit the parent's `width:400px`.

> The timeHeader and dayHeader stops sticking after I scroll 40%.

`position:sticky` makes the header to offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor (.parent) as expected. The reason it stops working after scrolling 40% is because the header is treated as "stuck" only before it [meets the opposite edge of its containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning).

> I want the overflow items to scroll. When I scroll I want headers to stick.

It's not clear how you want the overflow to look like, but instead of adding `overflow` on `parent`, it makes more sense to have each field scrolls individually. This can be achieved by adding `overflow-y:scroll` (or `auto`) to the two long lists instead. (`.dayslots` and time list container.) If you only want one scroll on `parent`, move it onto `parent` instead.

Next, these two lists have to shrink to fit into `parent` so that overflow will work. This can be done by flex-box `flex-direction:column`, and again we need to add `min-height:0` on the lists to allow them to shrink over their content size.

The modified html and css will look like this: (There are tricks [to hide the scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll), but they are outside the scope of this question)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  /*remove this since display:flex is shrinking its contents, there won't be any overflow*/
  /*move overflow here if you want to scroll all childs under .parent together*/
  /* overflow: scroll;*/
}

.timeslot {
  /*removed because not needed anymore*/
  /* position: sticky;*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  /* Allow it to shrink over its content width by .parent's display:flex*/
  min-width: 0;
  /*add the following 2 lines align the time header and contents*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.timeHeader,
.dayHeader {
  /* removed because not needed anymore*/
  /* position: sticky; */
  /* top: 0; */
  background-color: white;
}

.timeslots,
.dayslots {
  /*Again, allow it to shrink over its content height*/
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
}


/* Below CSS changed with the same logic above*/

.days {
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="timeslot">
    <div class="timeHeader">Time</div>
    <div class="timeslots">
      <ul>
        <li>7:00 a.m</li>
        <li>8:00 a.m</li>
        <li>9:00 a.m</li>
        <li>10:00 a.m</li>
        <li>11:00 a.m</li>
        <li>12:00 p.m</li>
        <li>1:00 p.m</li>
        <li>2:00 p.m</li>
        <li>3:00 p.m</li>
        <li>4:00 p.m</li>
        <li>5:00 p.m</li>
        <li>6:00 p.m</li>
        <li>7:00 p.m</li>
        <li>8:00 p.m</li>
        <li>9:00 p.m</li>
        <li>10:00 p.m</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="days">
    <div class="dayHeader">Days</div>
    <div class="dayslots">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The only nitpick I had was there were two vertical scrollbars one for timeslots and one for dayslots. I used react-scroll-sync to sync them and then hid the scrollbar for timeslots using CSS.

Comment: NP! If you want only one scroll simply move `overflow-y:scroll` onto `.parent` would work as well!

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is with .timeslots css property. Almost what you're looking for

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px; /* Adjusted for more height */
    overflow: auto; /* Changed to auto */
}

.timeHeader, .dayHeader {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.days {
    flex: 5;
    overflow-x: auto;
    }

li {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.dayslots {
    display: flex;
}
```